# Error with Random number generation in Swift on Linux?

Tags: swift, linux, random

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
extension Array {
  fileprivate func random() -> Element {
    let idx: Int
    #if os(Linux)
    idx = Int(random() % count)
    #else
    idx = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
    #endif

    return self[idx - 1]
  }
}
```

When I attempt to deploy my app it errors when running docker using linux, the issue as follows:

> error: binary operator '%' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int32' and 'Int'
>       idx = Int(rand() % count)

I tracked the issue down to this funciton but cant work out the fix here as it already is meant to provide an alternative handling for Linux...

Comment: Why reinvent this? `Array` provides the `randomElement` method already.

Comment: this is for vapor running on linux, i dont believe i have access to that method

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that `random()` returns `Int32`. So you need to convert one side.

```
idx = Int(random()) % count
```

Comment: this method threw the error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(Element)'
    idx = Int(random()) % count

Comment: It's probable getting confused between the math `random()` function and the `random` method you are adding to `Array`. Either prefix the call to `random()` as needed or rename the `random` method you are adding to `Array`.

Comment: I renamed the method with no luck, trying both the OP and your proposed reword, something else must be the issue!